# PDO::rowCount() returning -1

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

i have this function below. that i used to run on a *MySQL* DB. I had to move to a *SQL Server 2008*, easy thing.

But, after that, the `rowCount()` keeps returning `-1`, I've never had this happen before. I'm sure that my SQL query is returning the results, because if I do a `print_r()` on my return (the `$rows` var), everything gets printed.

So, if anyone had this issue, please help me to figure this out.

Sorry for any grammatical mistake.

```
public function listar(){

    $retorno = array();

    $sql = "SELECT m.id, m.descricao, m.link, m.categoria, m.icone FROM menus AS m,    grupos AS g, permissoes AS p WHERE (g.id = p.idgrupo AND m.id = p.idmenu) AND (p.status = :pstatus AND g.status = :gstatus AND m.status = :mstatus) AND g.id = :gid ORDER BY m.ordem ;";

    $vars = array(":pstatus"=>1,":gstatus"=>1,":mstatus"=>1,":gid"=>$_SESSION['group']);

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    foreach($vars as $index => $value){
        $stmt->bindValue($index,$value);
    }

    if($stmt->execute()){
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $rows['msg'] = '1';
        $rows['length'] = $count;

        $i = 0;
        while($i < $count){
            foreach($rows[$i] as $index => $value){
                $rows[$i]->$index = utf8_encode($value);
            }
            $i++;
        }

        return $rows;
    } else {
        return array("msg" => '0');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Got it guys.

The `prepare()` statement should receive one more parameter. `array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)` .

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql,array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));

After that the `rowCount()` should work fine.

Thanks for the answer @Rasclatt.

Comment: Hey you, know I tried! :D Glad it works out for you!

Comment: Hey there, I am also having the same problem as yours. I have supplied another parameter when I do the `prepare()` however my rowCount() still did not work. Any idea?

Comment: I will look for something else. But, FIY, i use `$stmt->execute()` instead of `$stmt->query($query)` which is the most common. I don't know which one u use and if that is a problem, but, if u use the last one, u should try with the first, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be running into the gotcha on the PDO `rowCount()` function. As stated in the PHP manual. The second sentence is the gotcha...:

*"If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behavior is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."*

Instead, you should use a `COUNT(*)` sql statement.

Comment: Agree with @Rasclatt. rowCount() doesn't always return the number of rows returned, rowCount() is mostly used for DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statements.

Comment: Yeah, but i didn't want to do another query just for the count(), so i was searching for another way. Thx guys.