# PDO rowCount keeps returning -1 with PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, sybase

I am puzzled with this problem for hours now. I have PHP code using PDO to access Sybase database. The problem is the function of `rowCount()` keeps returning the value of `-1` at all times. I found the solution here [PDO::rowCount() returning -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363413/pdorowcount-returning-1) and the user supply the parameter of `PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL` while preparing the query. That solution works for him but for some reason not for me. Appreciate if you guys can help me on this.

Here is my code:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false; //always first initialize to false
    if( $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)) ){
        $x = 1;
        if( count($params) ){
            foreach($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if( $this->_query->execute() ){
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            echo $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount(); //this line returns -1
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I will make a call to this function using something like this:

```
$data = $this->_db->query( "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?", array($user) );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Reading the php's docs, rowCount used for delete,insert,update, if you need the count of rows returned, why you dont use the count() function?

Comment: @Axel thank you for your reply. I am using the function for all queries SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE. So I am trying to stick to this one function for all statements types. How do I use that count() function. Do you mean count the result itself?

Answer (score 0):

I post my this own solution so that it helps somebody out there who might have same problem. So I followed other people solution to first calculate the rows returned and then if the number of rows is more than zero, we proceed the execution. My code is as below:

```
$sql = "SOME SQL STATEMENT HERE";

if( $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) as computedRow FROM ( {$sql} ) AS X", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL) ) ){
    $x = 1;
    if( count($params) ){
        foreach($params as $param){
            $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
            $x++;
        }
    }

    if( $this->_query->execute() ){

        $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        foreach ($this->_results as $obj){
            $this->_count = $obj->computedRow;
        }

        if($this->_count){
            if( $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare( $sql . $orderby , array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL) ) ){
                $x = 1;
                if( count($params) ){
                    foreach($params as $param){
                        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                        $x++;
                    }
                }
                if( $this->_query->execute() ){
                    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                }
                else {
                    $this->_error = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->_count = 0;
        }   
    } 
    else {
        $this->_error = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this could help somebody out there. Enjoy :)