# SQLalchemy rowcount always -1 for statements

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, rowcount

I was playing around with SQLalchemy and Microsoft SQL Server to get a hang of the functions when I came across a strange behavior. I was taught that the attribute rowcount on the result proxy object will tell how many rows were effected by executing a statement. However, when I select or insert single or multiple rows in my test database, I always get -1. How could this be and how can I fix this to reflect the reality?

```
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData()

# Ex1: select statement for all values
student = Table('student', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = select([student])
result_proxy = connection.execute(stmt)
results = result_proxy.fetchall()
print(result_proxy.rowcount)

# Ex2: inserting single values
stmt = insert(student).values(firstname='Severus', lastname='Snape')
result_proxy = connection.execute(stmt)
print(result_proxy.rowcout)
 
# Ex3: inserting multiple values 
stmt = insert(student)
values_list = [{'firstname': 'Rubius', 'lastname': 'Hagrid'},
               {'firstname': 'Minerva', 'lastname': 'McGonogall'}]
result_proxy = connection.execute(stmt, values_list)
print(result_proxy.rowcount)
```

The print function for each block seperately run example code prints -1. The Ex1 successfully fetches all rows and both insert statements successfully write the data to the database.

According to the following issue, the rowcount attribute isn't always to be trusted. Is that true here as well? And when, how can I compensate with a Count statement in a SQLalcehmy transaction?
[PDO::rowCount() returning -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363413/pdorowcount-returning-1)

Comment: when tested with an update statement, rowcount worked fine.

Comment: Returning -1 for rowcount is expected for a SELECT statement and for a multi-row INSERT statement (which uses `executemany`, and that [always returns -1](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/481)). I am unable to reproduce the issue for a single-row INSERT statement; your example code above returns 1 for me (after I fix the typo).

Comment: I didn't know that. can you suggest how to best use a Count statement to confirm how many records were effected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single-row `INSERT … VALUES ( … )` is trivial: If the statement succeeds then one row was affected, and if it fails (throws an error) then zero rows were affected.

For a multi-row `INSERT` simply perform it inside a transaction and rollback if an error occurs. Then the number of rows affected will either be zero or `len(values_list)`.

To get the number of rows that a SELECT *will* return, wrap the select query in a `SELECT count(*)` query and run that first, for example:

```py
select_stmt = sa.select([Parent])
count_stmt = sa.select([sa.func.count(sa.text("*"))]).select_from(
    select_stmt.alias("s")
)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execution_options(isolation_level="SERIALIZABLE")
    rows_found = conn.execute(count_stmt).scalar()
    print(f"{rows_found} row(s) found")
    results = conn.execute(select_stmt).fetchall()
for item in results:
    print(item.id)
```

Comment: Aha, I suspected that Count(*) could not be used in inserts. Do transactions work the same in core as they do ORM? WIth a few rephrased internet searches I couldn't find any examples with sqlalchemy core.

Comment: They are very similar, and in version 1.4 (currently in public beta) they have become even more consistent. I would suggest that you check out the [version 1.4 / 2.0 tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html), especially the section on [Working with Transactions and the DBAPI](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#tutorial-working-with-transactions).